# Rate of potential failure

Tags: statistics

I am seeking to discover what the probability of finding a failure in a unit based on quantities.

So the example is that I have three pallets of product that need to be inspected for failures.

Pallet one has 17 cases of product per layer, 68 cases total per pallet. Each case has 10 packages of product in each case.

Pallet two has 8 cases of product per layer, total of 40 cases per pallet. Each case has 30 packages of product per case.

Pallet three has 10 cases of product per layer, for a total of 60 cases per pallet. Each case has 12 packages of product in each case.

The inspection process requires checking four cases per layer for failure. What’s the probability of finding a failure in one layer based on package count of the case?

So say I pull four cases of ten from pallet one - 40 bags. 
I pull four cases of thirty from pallet two - 120 bags.
I pull four cases of twelve from pallet three - 48 bags.

Comment: It is going to depend on the probability of an individual package/bag failing and on whether failures are independent

Comment: So ideally the rate of failure is acceptable at a one in a thousand, so the expected failure rate is one in five hundred. The failures are normally a repeat problem with the occasional independent failure.